# Python - print items that are not in a list

Tags: python, list

I have a notepad that contains the following:

```
banana
apple
```

Additionally, I have a list. Say: `example_list = ["banana", "apple", "orange"]`

I want to print the values in example_list, that are not inside the notepad. So, desired outcome: `orange`

This is what I tried:

```
file = open("picturesLog.txt", "r")
fileLines = file.readlines()

example_list = ["banana", "apple", "orange"]

for item in example_list:
    if item in fileLines:
        pass
    else:
        print(item)
```

This is printing:

```
banana
apple
orange
```

Comment: using keyword `list` as variable name is a terrible idea...

Comment: Hi, this is just for testing purposes.

Comment: doesn't matter, it's something you should avoid at all cost. One day a simple test may make no sense just because of something as silly as that... :)

Comment: That's true, I have edited the post, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python reads the end-of-line character along with each line. You'll have to strip it off. Something like `fileLines = [x.strip() for x in file.readlines()]` should do the trick.

That would be the **first** change to make. It answers the original question.

The comments will be aflame with ways to improve the algorithm. Let them burn.

Comment: Good deal, didn't know about that. Thanks.

Comment: Best to drop the `.readlines()`; files already iterate by line, and using it means you'll double peak memory usage unnecessarily (one `list` of the unmodified lines, and the `list` you're building of the stripped lines, where omitting `.readlines()` means only the `list` of stripped lines is needed). Also, given the goal is membership testing, probably better to make a `set` (so large files cost no more per check than small ones). `fileLines = {x.strip() for x in file}`

Comment: @ShadowRanger what you say is true, but it addresses a different problem than the one asked about. Similar re: making a set instead of a list.

Comment: @Ian: In the original code the `readlines` made some sense to get the `list` of lines when you weren't otherwise modifying the lines. Once you wrap it in a list comprehension, the `readlines` becomes harmful; you're going to get the `list` no matter what, so doubling your memory requirements is problematic when you can just get rid of the `readlines`. `readlines` wasn't a problem in the OP's case, but it is a problem in your answer. I agree the `set` part not specifically a problem in either case, just an improvement that would apply to both.

Answer (score 1):

Or `str.join`:

```
l= set(map(str.rstrip,fileLines))
print('\n'.join([i for i in list if i not in l]))
```

Comment: If `l` is larger than a few elements, a `set` should be used.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> example_list = ["banana", "apple", "orange"]
>>> with open("picturesLog.txt") as f: 
...   seen = set(map(str.strip, f))
...   for fruit in set(example_list) - seen:
...     print(fruit)
... 
orange
```